# Return Base64 of Converted Filepicker.io Image

Tags: filepicker.io

The documentation shows you how to return a base64 version of an image using the "read" or "pick" function, but not for a converted one (i.e. filepicker.covert). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's not currently a way to do this in one step, but one thing you can do is combine the filepicker.read() and filepicker.convert() calls to first convert the file, then read the contents as base64.